# why os.path.isfile returns false if file is other directory?

Tags: python, pythonpath, os.path

Which path is used in os.path.isfile(filename) in python. 
I have file in /home/debian and I have added that path in PYTHONPATH variable still os.path.isfile(filename) returns FALSE.

Comment: What is the exact path you put?

Comment: Huh? `isfile()` is *supposed* to return false if you give it something (like a directory) that isn't a regular file. That's its job. (If that's not what you meant to ask, having an example in the question that reproduces the issue would be helpful).

Comment: _"I have file in..."_ What is the name *of this file*? _"...still os.path.isfile(filename) returns FALSE"_ - what is the value of `filename`? Provide specific and reproducible example.

Comment: exact path is /home/debian/   as PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 3):

If `filename`is relative, the current working directory (available with `os.getcwd()`) is used.

`PYTHONPATH` is only used when importing modules.

Comment: Ya I noticed that it do not show error while importing from other directory than current working directory.

Comment: os.path.isfile()  by default search in working directory

Comment: what can be done to make it search in other specified directory

Comment: @user8721345 You can use an absolute path, starting with `/` on Unix-like OS or `C:\ ` (or other drive letter) or `\\ ` on Windows. To join path and a filename together, there is `os.path.join()`